# Project Rider - Break on Exception

Tags: exception, breakpoints, rider

I can't find the option in JetBrains Project Rider to "Break on Exception".  Where I would normally add an exception breakpoint in IntelliJ, I see this:

[image]

Comment: Rider doesn't support this feature for now. I have created an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-1974

Comment: That feature is supported now. See @drew-noakes answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break on specific exceptions is not implemented yet. Now Rider can break only on unhandled exceptions. Will come soon.

Comment: How do I break only on unhandled exceptions?

Comment: Debugger should be paused automatically when unhandled exception occurs.

Comment: After additional testing, we may be going by different interpretations of "unhandled".  I was considering an exception that is thrown back to a certain layer (in this case MVC entry point) to be unhandled: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-2066

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Rider now supports this feature.

Answer (score 35):

There are two ways to do this.

## Break on all exceptions

Go to *Run* | *View Breakpoints...*. Click the green `+` icon. Select *Stop on all .NET exceptions*.

[image]

You can then modify the breakpoint:

[image]

---

## Break on a specific exception

Either use:

- *Run* | *Stop on exception...*
- *Run* | *View Breakpoints...*. Click the green `+` icon. Select *.NET exception breakpoints*.

Either approach will give you the following UI where you can search for an exception type:

[image]

To manage the settings, use the *Breakpoints* dialog.

Comment: I do not have a "Stop on all .NET exceptions" option in that dropdown.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me. But I'm wondering why this is not the default behavior and we need to explicitly turn it on ?

Comment: The menu options have changed but you can try selecting `CLR Exception Breakpoints` (and `Exception Breakpoints`) in the current version

Comment: Looks like the [new UI looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFbqm.png)