# JetBrains Rider - How to exclude a certain type of exception from break points

Tags: debugging, ide, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am new to JetBrains Rider and find it extremely handy for C# developing.
Just in our solution we have a certain type of exception that is thrown frequently.  When I debug I don't want it to break on this type of exception while I do want it to break on all other exceptions thrown.
It can be easily achieved by Visual Studio.

I found a post here [Project Rider - Break on Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150047/project-rider-break-on-exception/39155087#39155087) 
It told me how to break on a certain type of Exception.  But still no clue how to break on all Exceptions except this certain type.

Comment: Plus even "Enable external source debug" is unchecked, exception thrown from external code will still be break at.  Assume it's a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add exception breakpoint for all types and then add exception breakpoint for your certain type with unchecked 'Suspend' option

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I find that sometimes it is not very stable.  It ignores my settings at all.  But when it works stable it works the way you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Jetbrains > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger

> Exceptions:
>
> [x] Break on user-unhandled exceptions (excluding Mono)
>
> Except:
>
> *-> + Add your Exception here <-*