# Rider - Unity - Break on unhandled exception

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, rider

How can I setup Rider so that its debugger breaks/stops whenever there is an unhandled exception? In particular, I set up assertions all over my code, I attach the Rider debugger and I hit play on Unity. I can see on the console that many of the assertions are failing, but the debugger doesn't halt and let me debug, it just continues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150047/project-rider-break-on-exception
This might help

Comment: @Jay saw that, but it's too old I think. The options on the most recent version are different I'm afraid.